# Node express references error response is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
    
    
    var _expressPackage = require("express");  
            var _bodyParserPackage = require("body-parser");  
            var _sqlPackage = require("mssql");  
        //Initilize app with express web framework  
            var app = _expressPackage();  
        //To parse result in json format  
            app.use(_bodyParserPackage.json());  
          
        ***//Here we will enable CORS, so that we can access api on cross domain.***  
            app.use(function (req, res, next) {  
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");  
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");  
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, contentType,Content- 
   Type, 
            Accept, Authorization");  
            next();  
             });  
          
        ***//Lets set up our local server now.***  
            var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function () {  
            var port = server.address().port;  
            console.log("App now running on port", port);  
           });  
          
        ***//Set up your sql connection string, i am using here my own, you have to replace it with your 
         own.***  
            var dbConfig = {  
            user: "sa1",  
            password: "12345",  
            server: "localhost",  
            database: "test123"  
              };  
          
        ***//Function to connect to database and execute query***  
                  var QueryToExecuteInDatabase = function (response, strQuery) {  
            ***//close sql connection before creating an connection otherwise you will get an error if 
             connection already exists.***  
                   _sqlPackage.close();  
            //Now connect your sql connection  
                   _sqlPackage.connect(dbConfig, function (error) {  
                    if (error) {  
                       console.log("Error while connecting to database :- " + error);  
                       response.send(error);  
                    }  
                    else {  
                    ***//let's create a request for sql object***  
                        var request = new _sqlPackage.Request();  
                    //Query to run in our database  
                        request.query(strQuery, function (error, responseResult) {  
                            if (error) {  
                               console.log("Error while connecting to database:- " + error);  
                               response.send(error);  
                            }  
                            else {  
                                response.send(responseResult);  
                            }  
                        });  
                    }  
                });             
             }  
          
        ***//GET API***  
            app.get("/StudentList", function(_req ,_res){  
            var Sqlquery = "select * from student1";  ***//tbl_studentdetails***
            QueryToExecuteInDatabase(_res, Sqlquery);  
            });
    
        ***//call a stored procedure***
            var request = new _sqlPackage.Request();  
           ***//calling a stored procedure***  
                        request.input('Username', _sqlPackage.VarChar(50), 'admin');  
                        request.input('Password', _sqlPackage.VarChar(50), 'admin@123');  
                        request.execute('sp_CheckLogin', function (err, recordsets, returnValue) {  
                            response.send(recordsets);  
                        });
    
    

>  (D:\performalytic\9999.practice\angularpra\NodeApiWithSql\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:701:23)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:463:21)
- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This question could use a bit more clarity... but with the limited information provided it appears the issue you are running into here has to do with **lexical scope**.

Lexical scope most simply has to do with what variables the current execution context has access to. Inside of a function, you can either access variables declared within the function... or in the surrounding code. The last line of your code snipped shows a top level variable `request` and a method on that object called `execute`.

The callback you are passing the `execute` method has three variables (function parameters) you're naming `err`, `recordsets`, and `returnValue`. Yet inside that function body you're attempting to access a variable named `response`. If we look in the surrounding code... there is no `response` variable declared. (The only variable named `response` I see is within the `QueryToExecuteInDatabase`, and therefore only accessible within that function body.

Where are you getting this templated code from?